# ExtJs how to create and manage dynamic views under one controller

Tags: javascript, extjs

I know the MVC concept in ExtJs just very briefly. Could you please help me to fill up the **knowledge gaps** please? I only know how to create a single view this way...

```
Ext.define('My.controller.Contacts', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    stores: ['Contacts'],
    views: ['ContactsGrid'],
    refs: [{ref: 'grid', selector: '', xtype: 'contacts-grid', autoCreate: true}],

    getGrid: function() {
        var g = this.getGrid();
        return g;
    }
});
```

`this.getGrid()` seems to give you the same grid view. But what if:

1. I want to create multiple instances of grid views dynamically, how? and where do I store them by convention?
2. For each view I have created, I want to give it a config object, like how I do `Ext.create(somecontrol, config);` but this case in MVC they are in refs? Where do I insert this config object for every view instance I create?
3. I have a store `Contacts`, what is the relationship between all these views and the store? One each, or all sharing one store?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all of these the answer is going to be "it depends",

1. I would create dynamic views in the view definition if it's something that you read at startup, otherwise if you are clicking on a button and adding a view element, you could have everything in the controller, or you could have the controller call a method on the view that actually creates the view. I'd probably go with the latter but it depends on how you want to encapsulate your view logic.

   As far as 'storing' these views is concerned, the convention is to give your views an unique id so you can reference it later, similar to DOM lookups. But you can also store references to a component in a variable obviously. It really depends on what you are doing. If a controller is constructing a bunch of dynamic elements, it might make sense to just hold on to references to those elements in the controller.
2. Views are typically defined in their own files under the MVC approach, essentially this is an Ext.define block with a configuration in it. There are a few sample MVC applications on the Sencha site, I recommend looking them over.
3. This really depends on what your doing. If you have multiple Contacts views, it might make sense to have a single store be referenced by multiple views, but in general Stores represent a collection of specific data. Like Books, or Contacts, or Employees. So if a view needs to show Books and Employees, it would make sense to references those stores in the view.

I think the crux of what you're asking is where do I encapsulate the logic for dynamic views. **I would recommend creating reusable view components that encapsulate your display logic and have the controller create these components and give them the data to populate themselves.** This gives you a nice flexible separation of concerns.

If you're just getting started with ExtJS and their implementation of MVC I highly recommend playing around with Sencha Architect. I wouldn't build a real project with it, but it's great for throwing together quick little demo apps, and it generates an MVC structure for you. Take a look at what it gives you and take a look at the demo applications on the Sencha site.

Comment: I can't accept it as answer, yet. You are right "creating reusable view components that encapsulate your display logic and have the controller create these components" it is what I don't actually know how to code, can't find any example on the web...I have the general knowledge of MVC, also aware of DeftJs, built a couple of simple projects using Sencha Architect 2. However, ExtJs 4 MVC structure has been my knowledge gap, especially with how to create dynamic viewson the spot for a controller. Could you show me some code please?

Comment: @Tom, If your having trouble finding examples I would actually recommend going straight to the source looking at the Sencha ExtJS code base. Almost all of their view components are using a component hierarchy and should give you example of how to extend that hierarchy. That's basically how I learn how to work with ExtJS.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code to explain as well.  The button text config is set to 'ZZZ' in my example. The component being instantiated from view 'view-XXX' (xtype) extends 'Ext.window.Window' in my example.  If a component is being instantiated within a view, the Ext.create is implicit when using lazy instantiation via the xtype config.  If a component is being instantiated within the controller, I use the standard notation Ext.create.  If you want to give an id, use the Ext.id() to dynamically generate an id for the component.  I won't repeat @James' answer for #2 and #3.

**Try this:**

```
Ext.define('App.controller.ControllerExample', {
    extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',

    stores: ['XXXs', 'YYYs'],
    models: ['XXX', 'YYY'],

    refs : [{
        ref: 'viewport',
        selector: 'view-viewport'
    }, {
        ref: 'XXX',
        selector: 'view-XXX-window'
    }, {
        ref: 'YYY',
        selector: 'view-YYY'

    }],

    init : function() {

        this.control({

            'view-XXX-window': {

                minimize: function(win, obj) {

                    this.getXXX().hide();
                },

                close: function(panel, eOpt) {

                    this.getXXX().hide();
                }
            },

            'view-XXX-window button[text=ZZZ]': {

                click: function() {

                    var XXX = this.getXXX();

                    if (XXX === undefined) {

                        var viewportWidth = this.getViewport().getWidth();
                        var viewportHeight = this.getViewport().getHeight();
                        var windowWidth = viewportWidth * 0.9;
                        var windowHeight = viewportHeight * 0.9;
                        var x = (viewportWidth / 2) - (windowWidth / 2);
                        var y = (viewportHeight / 2) - (windowHeight / 2);

                        XXX = Ext.create('App.view.XXX', {
                            x: x,
                            y: y,
                            width: windowWidth,
                            height: windowHeight
                        });

                        XXX.show();

                    }
                    else {

                        XXX.show();
                    }
                }
            },

        });
    },

});
```